# Clojure macros: Passing filtered map and arity to other macro based on condition

Tags: clojure

```
(defmacro action1 [] `(prn "action1" ~'start ~'etype1))

(defmacro block [bindings & body] 
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [(if (symbol? k) k (symbol (name k))) `'~v]) (cond
                     (map? bindings) bindings
                     (symbol? bindings) (var-get (resolve bindings))
                     :else (throw (Exception. "bindings must be map or symbol"))))]
       ~body))

(defmacro bar [ctx arity & expr]
      `(let [~'t1 "lv" ~'np (prn "bar_1st_let" '~ctx ~ctx '~arity ~arity '~arity(resolve (first '~arity)) )
            ] 
            (block ~ctx ;;~ctx = {start "s1" top "x"}
              (fn '~arity ;; '~arity = [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1]
                (let [~'__execonceresult 1]
                  (do ~@expr)     
                )
              )
            )
        )
  )

(defmacro foo_multi [metadata ctxv aritym & expr]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `~v]) metadata) ~'np (prn "foo_multi_1st_let" '~aritym)] 
  (fn ~aritym 
      (for [~'ctx (filter #(= (% (some (fn [~'m] (if (= (name ~'m) "top") ~'m)) (keys %))) ~'etype) '~ctxv)]
        (do (prn "foo_multi_b4_case" ~'ctx ~'etype ~aritym)
        (case ~'etype
        "x"
          (let [[~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1] ~aritym ~'np (prn "foo_multi_2nd_let" ~'ctx ~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1)]
            (bar ~'ctx [~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1] ~@expr))
        "y"
          (let [[~'etype2 ~'cid2 ~'id2 ~'pl2] ~aritym]
            (bar ~'ctx [~'etype2 ~'cid2 ~'id2 ~'pl2] ~@expr))
        ))))))

(def foo (foo_multi { meta1 "m1" meta2 "m2" } [{start "s1" top "x"} 
  {start "s3" top "x"} {start "s2" top "y"}] [etype a1 a2 a3] (block {toc "c"} 
   (block {c1 "d"} (action1)) "end"))
   )

(let [myarr ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1 "q" 2}]] (apply foo myarr))
```

---

Unable to pass arity from bar macro to block macro and getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
The rest of the code executes if I comment the block call from the bar macro.

```
(defmacro bar [ctx arity & expr]
      `(let [~'t1 "lv" ~'np (prn "bar_1st_let" '~ctx ~ctx '~arity ~arity '~arity(resolve (first '~arity)) )
            ] 
            (comment block ~ctx ;;~ctx = {start "s1" top "x"}
              (fn '~arity ;; etype specific ~arity eg: [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1]
                (let [~'__execonceresult 1]
                  (do ~@expr) ;; uses etype1     
                )
              )
            )
        )
  )
```

After commenting below is the output of the debug lines :

```
"foo_multi_1st_let" [etype a1 a2 a3]
"foo_multi_b4_case" {start "s1", top "x"} "x" ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}]
"foo_multi_2nd_let" {start "s1", top "x"} "x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}
"bar_1st_let" ctx {start "s1", top "x"} [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1] ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}] [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1] nil
"foo_multi_b4_case" {start "s3", top "x"} "x" ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}]
"foo_multi_2nd_let" {start "s3", top "x"} "x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}
"bar_1st_let" ctx {start "s3", top "x"} [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1] ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1, "q" 2}] [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1] nil
```

---

As per the debug lines printed above, In the bar macro I am unable to resolve first arity symbol and it is printed nil (Don't know the reason why). The goal is to pass arity correctly from bar macro to the block macro and be able to access and print start and etype1 value in action1 macro.

Comment: This is quite a read. Are you sure it is a minimal case?

Comment: yes it is the minimal case

Comment: Please update the question to clarify the goal, and add an example of what is going wrong.

Comment: @AlanThompson I have updated the question and added ouput of debug lines as well. Hope it is more clear and detailed then the previous one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @I0st3d pointed out, this could be your solution after modifing bar definition and foo_multi will become like above solution my-multi-let.

```
(defmacro action1 [] `(prn "action1" ~'start ~'etype))

(defn named-type? [m] (when (= (name m) "top") m))

(defmacro block [ctx & expr] 
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `~v]) ctx)] ~@expr))

(defmacro bar [bindings & body]
  `(block ~bindings (if (= ~'top ~'etype) (do 
     ~@body))))

(defmacro foo_multi [metadata bindings-list arity & body]
  (let [fns (->> bindings-list
       (map (fn [b] `(bar ~b ~arity ~@body))))
  ] `(block ~metadata (fn ~arity (do ~@fns)))
))

(def foo (foo_multi {meta1 "m1" meta2 "m2"} [{start "s1" top "x"} 
  {start "s2" top "y"}] [etype a1 a2 a3] 
(block {toc "c"} (block {c1 "d"} (action1)) "end")
))

(let [myarr ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1 "q" 2}]] (apply foo myarr))
```

In bar macro you'll get all arity params accessible, so you can create a map vars varying for etype specific symbols also if required.
your **(let [myarr ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1 "q" 2}]] (apply foo myarr))** will also work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting a NullPointer caused by your `action1` macro returning `nil` and the `block` macro trying to execute the response from `action1`. A splicing quote would fix that. Also, it looks to me like there are too many quotes on the values of the bindings in `block`, so I've taken them out too.

```
(defmacro block [bindings & body]
  (let [bs (->>
            (cond
              (map? bindings)    bindings
              (symbol? bindings) []
              :else              (throw (Exception. "bindings must be map or symbol")))
            (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [(if (symbol? k) k (symbol (name k))) v])))]
    `(let [~@bs]
     ~@body)))
```

Secondly, `clojure.core/resolve` will [only look up vars in a namespace](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-resolve), not locals created by `clojure.core/let` or `clojure.core/fn`. So if you try and resolve a local you will get `nil`.

```
(defmacro bar [bindings arity & expr]
  `(block ~bindings ;;~bindings = {start "s1" top "x"}
          (fn ~arity ;; '~arity = [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1]
            (let [~'__execonceresult 1]
              (do ~@expr)))))

(macroexpand-1 '(bar {start "s1" top "x"} [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1] (action1)))
;; =>
(do
 (user/block
  {start "s1", top "x"}
  (clojure.core/fn
   [etype1 cid1 id1 pl1]
   (clojure.core/let [__execonceresult 1] (do (action1))))))
```

So this part of `foo_multi` now runs.

```
(block {toc "c"} (block {c1 "d"} (action1)) "end")
;;=>
"action1" :start :etype1
"end"
```

In `foo_multi`:

```
(defn named-top? [m]
  (when (= (name m) "top")
    m)) 

(defmacro foo_multi [metadata ctxv aritym & expr]
  (prn "foo_multi" (map #(get % (some named-top? (keys %))) ctxv))
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) metadata)]
     (prn "foo_multi_1st_let" '~aritym)
     (fn ~aritym
       (for [~'ctx (filter #(= (get % (some named-top? (keys %))) ~'etype) '~ctxv)]
         (do #_ (prn "foo_multi_b4_case" ~'ctx ~'etype ~aritym)
             (case ~'etype
               "x"
               (let [[~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1] ~aritym ~'np (prn "foo_multi_2nd_let" ~'ctx ~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1)]
                 (bar ~'ctx [~'etype1 ~'cid1 ~'id1 ~'pl1] ~@expr))
               "y"
               (let [[~'etype2 ~'cid2 ~'id2 ~'pl2] ~aritym]
                 (bar ~'ctx [~'etype2 ~'cid2 ~'id2 ~'pl2] ~@expr))))))))
```

the filter `(filter #(= (get % (some named-top? (keys %))) ~'etype) '~ctxv)` seems like that will error because `etype` won't exist unless it's forced to be in the `metadata` argument. It's generally a bad idea to create these magic locals with the `~'idiom` because you never know what you're shadowing and it's just spooky action at a distance. It's better to use the `gensym` feature of `syntax-quote` `local#` as [described here](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#syntax_quote).

Just as a comment on debugging strategy, trying to extract a simplified minimal case would have probably helped you understand what was going on. This code is rather confused I think. There's a whole bunch of stuff hacked together. It reads like you're leaning about Clojure and macros and biting off too much in one go. I think that you're trying to replicate lexical scope with these macros but I'm not totally sure what the end goal is. Maybe reading through [this](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms) will help.

Also, I suspect you're going to run into trouble when you discover that `clojure.core/for` is lazy.

`foo_multi` returns a function that returns a list of functions. So to actually execute the majority of the code you've written, you'll need to call those functions.

```
(let [start  :start
      etype1 :etype1
      foo    (foo_multi {meta1 "m1" meta2 "m2" }
                        [{start "s1" top "x"} 
                         {start "s3" top "x"}
                         {start "s2" top "y"}]
                        [etype a1 a2 a3]
                        (block {toc "c"} 
                               (block {c1 "d"} (action1))
                               "end"))
      args   ["x" 100 200 {"p" 1 "q" 2}]
      fns    (apply foo args)]
  (map #(apply % args) fns))
```

If you are trying to replicate lexical scope using maps instead of vectors, perhaps this code snippet will help you rethink your approach:

```
(defmacro my-let [bindings & body]
  (let [bs (vec (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) bindings))]
    `(let ~bs
       ~@body)))

(defmacro my-multi-let [bindings-list & body]
  (->> bindings-list
       (map (fn [b] `(my-let ~b ~@body)))
       (cons `list)))

(macroexpand-1 '(my-let {a "a1" b "b1"} [a b]))
(macroexpand-1 '(my-multi-let [{a "a1" b "b1"} {a "a2" b "b2"}] [a b]))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was feeling that I’d have to try and unwind it myself at some point:-)

Comment: @pete23 it wasn't that bad in the end. Still not sure what the actual aim of the code is.

Comment: @l0st3d Thank for the answer. I tried making changes suggested by you. Also realised that `clojure.core/for` being lazy is casuing the problem. Hence i

Comment: Hence I made changes in foo_multi as `clojure.core/for` being lazy, but still bar macro is exec only once. 

`(defmacro foo_multi [metadata ctxv aritym & expr]
  (let [ctx (filter #(= (get % (some named-top? (keys %))) "x") ctxv)
        st (map (fn[b] `(bar ~b ~aritym ~@expr)) ctx)]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) metadata)] (do ~@st))
))`
   
`(let* [meta1 "m1" meta2 "m2"] (do (user/bar {start "s1", top "x"} [etype a1 a2 a3] (block {toc "c"} (block {c1 "d"} (action1)) "end")) (user/bar {start "s3", top "x"} [etype a1 a2 a3] (block {toc "c"} (block {c1 "d"} (action1)) "end"))))`

Comment: @Jai So do you still have a question? Or have we unpicked all your bugs? If you still have a query, can you edit your question please? Maybe include the error your getting and what you're expecting? Or is this question answered?

Comment: @l0st3d how do I evaluate the list of function objects returned by for loop in foo_multi macro ?

Comment: @jai I've added a code snippet to the answer that will actually call the functions you've written

Comment: @l0st3d The snipppet calls the functions, but now it gives `Unable to resolve symbol: start in this context` . My goal was to print ~'start and ~'etype1 in action1 macro. It seems these symbols are not accessible there.

Comment: @jai I've changed the code so those symbols are defined. I'd put definitions for them in the global scope.

Comment: @l0st3d It didnt help. It is prining the keword :start. o/p  `"action1" :start "x"`

Comment: Yes. That's the value of the start symbol. I still have no idea what you're actually trying to do. You could really do with trying to explain what problem you're solving.