# issue in clojure macro creating symbols for each element in map array

Tags: clojure

Basically I'm new to macro and trying in macro to create symbols from array of maps and getting error: 
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
But am able to make it work for map instead of array of maps and calling 
(gensym-of-map ~args ~ctx)
Please help how to solve gensym-of-amap macro

```
(defmacro gensym-of-amap[args ctx]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `~v]) ctx)] 
     (prn "access ~args via ~'aa ~'bb and ctx syms ~'a"))
  ) 
(defmacro gensyms[ctx args] 
  `(let [] (fn ~args
     (for [~'c '~ctx]
       (gensym-of-amap ~args ~'c) ;run foreach ctx
        )))) 
(def test-macro (gensyms [{a 1} {a 2}] [aa bb])) 
(apply test-macro [1 2])
```

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're trying to do with this code. Can you clarify what your intent is?

Comment: Basically I am trying to generate symbols from ~’c map in for loop, which gives 1 and 2 values on printing ~’a

Comment: You seem to be solving a similar puzzle to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826777/clojure-macros-passing-filtered-map-and-arity-to-other-macro-based-on-condition ...

Comment: I think you're getting into trouble using the unquote/quote idom for putting literals in macros. You should almost never do put `~'symbol` in a macro. If you could state the problem, that would help us work out where you're going wrong.